# Letting a Batch file Minimize a DOS window?

Tags: windows, minimize, shrink

So i'm kinda into MS-DOS and such again, but i came to ask myself, How can i minimize a DOS window?
Any kind would be ok, minimalize, shrink to a tiny blue block.

I just can't seem to find a way to let it work on my Windows XP computer, is realy evrything excluded in XP?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you could do is create a windows program that will find the title of the cmd window you are running in and in that program minimize it. In Win32 you would use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) command to get a window handle, then [CloseWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632678(VS.85).aspx) to minimize it. Something like this *totally untested* program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HWND wnd = FindWindow(      
        NULL,
        argv[1]
        );
    CloseWindow(wnd);
    return 0;
}
```

Within the cmd window you could set the title to some string that you define (to avoid ambiguities) and then pass that name to the program to your program:

```
C:\>title TitleOfWindowToMiniMize

C:\>minimizeWindow TitleOfWindowToMiniMize
```

Comment: nice, this is 100% what i want :)

Answer (score 6):

You can start a program in a new minimised window using the `start` command:

```
start /min your_command_here
```

Comment: yeah, this might do the trick! tough would be awesome if i could minimise while running...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not in DOS. DOS has no concepts of windows.

In Windows you could write a little program that will look up your window and send it the appropriate message causing it to minimize. The same way you could also maximize or hide/show your window.