# Is there a programmatic way to minimize the Win7 Command Prompt window I'm working in?

Tags: windows, command-line

So I'm programming away in a Command Prompt window and I'm done.  I would like to minimize it and move on.  My fingers are already on the keyboard, I would like to just enter `min` or whatever and have the window go away instead of picking up the mouse and clicking on the minimize button.  Sort of like entering `exit`, except I don't want the window to die.  Is there a way to program this rather than use keyboard commands? Win7, regular command.exe.

Just figured it out, for those who might care.

`use Modern::Perl;
use Win32::GUI();
my $perlwindow = Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow();
Win32::GUI::Minimize($perlwindow);`

Comment: Did you try `Alt`+`Space`, `N`?

Comment: Good idea, I was fixated on a command vs. the interface.  But I was hoping for something a little easier to type.  I would almost as soon as use the mouse!  But that will work if nothing else does.

Comment: If you're on Windows 7, win key + down arrow minimises

Comment: I changed the question a bit to make it clear that I'm interested in a programmatic way of doing this, not in using the UI.

Comment: Uhm, a console application isn't supposed to mess with its window, if you want full control over your interface you should probably write a GUI application.

Comment: The accepted answer here seems to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775703/letting-a-batch-file-minimize-a-dos-window

Comment: voted to close as duplicate. "off-topic" vote reasons do not apply, to my opinion. this is not off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to add the behavior you desire. You can add a [hotstring](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) for "min" that will [minimize](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) the current window.

Or, instead of a hotstring (which relies on ahk running) you can make a script that minimizes the current window, [compile it into an executable](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) called "min.exe", and put that somewhere where your PATH has access. Then you just run the command. This also removes the need to add validation that `min` was typed in a shell window rather than, say, Word.

Sample (untested) script which will minimize the window when `min` + an [ending character](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) (space, period, enter) is typed:

```
::min::
WinMinimize, A
return
```

Comment: "you can make a script that minimizes the current window" - wasn't that the thing OP asked, is there a way to make such a script? and why would you compile it to an executable?

Comment: By "script" I mean AutoHotkey script, so compiling it is an alternative to having AHK always running on your system. And as for how to write the script, I linked the documentation for getting started. If you think that's not a complete enough answer, I'm adding a sample script.